# Запуск приложения через python

Tags: python

Есть способ открытия сайта:

```
webbrowser.open("ссылка")
```

Но также, по мимо открытия сайта, возможно есть открытие приложений, так какой модуль/строку нужно прописать для открытия приложения на Пк?

Comment: Нет такого способа открытия сайта. Я запустил эту строчку и получилась ошибка.

Comment: Модуль webbrowser используется. Если вам надо - pip install webbrowser

Comment: конечно же pip install webbrowser не будет работать  модуль webbrowser - стандартный и его надо импортировать, а не устанавливать.

Comment: Насколько я понял, Вы хотите открыть любое приложение на ПК? Если это так, то для этого есть модули os и, если не ошибаюсь, subprocess. К ответу прилагаю ссылку на пример кода: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/how+to+open+application+using+python Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

```sh
python -m webbrowser -t ""
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
os.startfile(r'C:/Users/Johnny/AppData/Roaming/Telegram Desktop/t1/Telegram.exe')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Есть модуль, `subprocess`, который позволяет запускать системные команды (которые есть в консоле). А при помощи таких команд можно запустить необходимое приложение.

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["calc.exe"])
```

Очень подробный ответ о возможности `subprocess.run` есть на [английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-do-i-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command/89243#89243) StackOverflow